# Null value when retreived from a list map, but not null when printed as a string

Tags: flutter

Can't seem to find why the value is equal to null when in fact it isn't.

if I do a print(studioName); it will print the value retrieved from Firestore Database.
But when I try to retrieve it from the list, it will print as a null.

```
String studioName;

class Homne extends StatefulWidget {

  @override

  _HomneState createState() => _HomneState();
}

class _HomneState extends State<Homne> {
  CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('PopularPlacesList');

  getPopularPlaces() async {
    final snapShot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('PopularPlacesList')
        .doc('ksx1hVJn4Jf46ACFBbp7')
        .get();
     var data = snapShot.data();
      studioName = data['name'];
        }
   var popularPlacesList = [
    {
      'name': '$studioName',
      'image': 'assets/popular_places/miami.jpg',
      'property': '783 properties'
    },
    {
      'name': 'Singapore',
      'image': 'assets/popular_places/singapore.jpg',
      'property': '593 properties'
    },
    {
      'name': 'New York',
      'image': 'assets/popular_places/newyork.jpg',
      'property': '1025 properties'
    },
    {
      'name': 'Venice',
      'image': 'assets/popular_places/venice.jpg',
      'property': '290 properties'
    },
    {
      'name': 'Vietnam',
      'image': 'assets/popular_places/vietnam.jpg',
      'property': '193 properties'
    }
  ];
```

Where the code is presented in a list view builder:

```
Container(
          width: width,
          height: 150.0,
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: popularPlacesList.length,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              var item = popularPlacesList[index];
```

Comment: Where do you call `getPopularPlaces()`? Also, while initializing `popularPlacesList`, `studioName` is probably still null. Initialize `popularPlacesList` _after_ you've set `studioName`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`popularPlacesList` is initialized before `getPopularPlaces` has finished loading. One solution would be to set `popularPlacesList` via `setState` after you've finished loading your data from Firestore.

```dart
class _HomneState extends State<Homne> {
  CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('PopularPlacesList');

  var popularPlacesList = [];

  getPopularPlaces() async {
    final snapShot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('PopularPlacesList')
        .doc('ksx1hVJn4Jf46ACFBbp7')
        .get();
     final data = snapShot.data();
     final studioName = data['name'];
     setState(() => popularPlacesList = [
      {
        'name': '$studioName',
        'image': 'assets/popular_places/miami.jpg',
        'property': '783 properties'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Singapore',
        'image': 'assets/popular_places/singapore.jpg',
        'property': '593 properties'
      },
      {
        'name': 'New York',
        'image': 'assets/popular_places/newyork.jpg',
        'property': '1025 properties'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Venice',
        'image': 'assets/popular_places/venice.jpg',
        'property': '290 properties'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Vietnam',
        'image': 'assets/popular_places/vietnam.jpg',
        'property': '193 properties'
      }
    ]);
  }
  // Rest of your class
}
```

Comment: Fixed, much appreciated!

Comment: If it helped you feel free to mark this answer as accepted. Glad to help! :)